# Laravel TNTsearch custom index creation and usage for large SQL database table

Tags: sql, laravel, indexing

Here is my situation, context, and dilemma.

**Situation**

I'm fairly new to Laravel and still learning the ropes. I recently installed TNTSearch and Laravel Scout and was able to create a model index using the below config. I created the index using the console command `php artisan tntsearch:import "App\Models\Product"` and can fuzzy search successfully with `App\Models\Product::search($keyword)->get()`.

**config/scout.php**

```
'tntsearch' => [
    'storage' => storage_path() . '/index',
    'fuzziness' => 'auto',
    'fuzzy' => [
        'prefix_length' => 2, 
        'max_expansions' => 50, 
        'distance' => 4,
    ],
    'asYouType' => true
],
```

**Context**

I have an SQL database table with over 30k+ product records segmented per province (Canadian project), and instead of searching the whole index and later filter by market, I’d like to create one index per market and launch a search for a given market.  I believe it will speed up the search and avoid returning results which will later be discarded! So basically having one product index file per province (i.e. `products_on.index,` `products_qc.index`, ...)

**Dilemma/Issue**

I am unable to find how to create such an index, have it update automatically and also how to use it.  I scoured the Internet for tutorial/guidance and could only find scarce information I can hardly put together.  I’d appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or guide me on how to implement such a thing.

No answer is wrong, and any bits and pieces of information can help me greatly to “get up to speed.”

**EDIT** (July 30th, 2018):

I still haven't found the answer to my request but the more I search, the more I'm concluding search indexes are "tied" to a model, and it is not possible to have more than one index per model.  So I would have to create one model extension per market from the original `Listings` model (Listings_QC, Listings_ON, ...).  Then create an index per markets and search from those (`Listings_QC::search(...)`).

I'm not keen to create models based on data!  Is this a good approach/practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RESOLVED !**

My inexperience with Laravel search index in general lead me in the wrong direction!
I finally found a document explaining how to use `searchBoolean()` to search using "and".  Modified my config as below to add the searchBoolean:

```
'tntsearch' => [
    'storage' => storage_path() . '/index',
    'fuzziness' => 'auto',
    'fuzzy' => [
        'prefix_length' => 2, 
        'max_expansions' => 50, 
        'distance' => 4,
    ],
    'asYouType' => true,
    'searchBoolean' => true
],
```

Then specify the market using the model's method `toSearchableArray()`, and add the market to any requested seach keyword.

For example, listing search with 'Alsace' for a QC market, I launch the search as
`Listings::search('Alsace QC')->get()`.

Voilà!  May help others hitting the same "wall"!

Comment: It's more than a years since you posted this. Any next workaround ?  The above solution Looks like a logical explanation. Will try this and update here.

Comment: Hemant, I finally ended up using MySql internal full text search indexing as the amount of data made update of the TNTSearch too heavy and long.  But this workaround worked good.

Comment: I agree. `TNTSearch` is great but the overhead for larger databases is too much.  My data set size is kinda around 2.5m but the indexing is becoming a pain. Moreover, my data set is yet too small for using Algolia or Elastic Search. ** Won't wanna pay**  might go down with your approach.